# how to hook the array field in postgreSql with mybatis-plus?

Tags: postgresql, mybatis-plus

I tried to hook the field "path" in my custom class "category" with a List or Array class to a column in my postgreSql with a data type of int4[], but I failed. The code is as follows (note, using the kotlin language and springboot framework)
(By the way, I tried building a bean in java, but springboot couldn't scan the java bean)

```
data class Category(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val path :IntArray
) {
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.argentrise.antinomy.interaction.dao.mapper.CategoryMapper">
    <resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="com.argentrise.antinomy.interaction.entity.Category">
        <id column="id" property="id" />
        <result column="name" property="name" />
        <result column="path" property="path" />
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

```
@Mapper
interface CategoryMapper : BaseMapper<Category> {
}
```

```
interface IPlayerService {
    fun getPlayer() : Player
    fun getCategory() : Category
}
```

```
@Service
class PlayerService : IPlayerService{

    @Autowired
    lateinit var categoryMapper : CategoryMapper

    override fun getCategory(): Category {
        val query : QueryWrapper<Category> = QueryWrapper()
        return categoryMapper.selectList(query)[0]
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/player")
class PlayerController {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var playerService : PlayerService

    @GetMapping("/test")
    fun test() : Category{
        println("@-@")
        return playerService.getCategory()
    }


}
```

crash-report :
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray to [I
at java.base/java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3946) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.instantiateClass(DefaultObjectFactory.java:74) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.applyConstructorAutomapping(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:751) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createByConstructorSignature(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:703) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:669) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:642) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:404) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForSimpleResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:361) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:335) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:308) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:201) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:65) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:325) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:89) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:151) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:145) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140) ~[mybatis-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:427) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.7.jar:2.0.7]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy78.selectList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:224) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.7.jar:2.0.7]
at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperMethod.executeForMany(MybatisMapperMethod.java:166) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperMethod.execute(MybatisMapperMethod.java:77) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MybatisMapperProxy.java:148) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperProxy.invoke(MybatisMapperProxy.java:89) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy84.selectList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.argentrise.antinomy.interaction.service.PlayerService.getCategory(PlayerService.kt:34) ~[main/:na]
at com.argentrise.antinomy.interaction.controller.PlayerController.test(PlayerController.kt:25) ~[main/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0-release-358]
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Instance.call(CallerImpl.kt:113) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0-release-358]
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callDefaultMethod$kotlin_reflection(KCallableImpl.kt:200) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0-release-358]
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:112) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0-release-358]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod$KotlinDelegate.invokeFunction(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:318) ~[spring-web-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:250) ~[spring-web-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181) ~[spring-web-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:918) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1086) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:143) ~[spring-session-core-3.2.0-M1.jar:3.2.0-M1]
at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82) ~[spring-session-core-3.2.0-M1.jar:3.2.0-M1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]

application.yml:

```
server:
  port: xxxx
  tomcat.uri-encoding: UTF-8
  servlet:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
      force: true
      enabled: true
  reactive:
    session:
      timeout: 30
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/antinomy
    username: xxxxxx
    password: xxxxxx
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  #文件大小设置
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 4096MB
      max-request-size: 4096MB
      enabled: true #开启
  web:
    resources:
      add-mappings: false


mybatis-plus:
  configuration:
    map-underscore-to-camel-case: true
    log-impl: org.apache.ibatis.logging.stdout.StdOutImpl
  mapper-locations: classpath*:/mapper/*.xml
```